# Should we use "if" or "when" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conditional-constructions, future-constructions

> 1)We will go to restaurant , if our son completes his work

> 2)We will go to restaurant , when our son completes his work.

Meaning wise, we will go to restaurant only if/when son completes his work. Do they both mean the same except one is conditional other is not??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two is that “when” implies certainty. You are sure your son will complete his work, and then you will go to the restaurant.

“If” is uncertain. Your son might complete his work, or he might not. If he does, you will go to the restaurant.

Also, you need to add “the” before “restaurant.”

Comment: So both sentences are correct with the different meanings